# What's the proper way to handle a variable across multiple methods?

Tags: c#

Say I have a `List<Objects>`. I want to define the list of objects in one method, and use them in several others.

Here's the ways I've come up with and I'm looking for more or the correct way to do it.

1. You can define `List<Objects>` in every method that uses it.

   - Pros: It works. No chance of getting the wrong variable.
   - Cons: Code duplication.
2. You can use a private `List<Objects>` defined in the class and update it using `(ref ListObjects)`

   - Pros: I only have to define it once.
   - Cons: I feel like it's messy and bad practice.
3. You can pass `List<Objects>` as a parameter to the methods that use it.

   - Pros: Prevents code duplication
   - Cons: Have to make my populate functions return functions, and add parameters to my other methods. Possible conflicts with Events?

So that's what I've come up with. I'm really not sure which to use or if there's a better way to do this. Thoughts?

EDIT: Including some code as requested.

```
private List<MedicalPlan> medicalPlansList;
```

This is the list. It is a list that gets information from a database, here:

```
private void BindMedicalList()
{
   medicalPlansList = new MedicalPlanRepository().RetrieveAll().Where(x => x.Year == year).ToList();
}
```

Then it's used to find objects in that list, such as

```
var result =
                    medicalPlansList.FirstOrDefault(
                        c => c.CoverageLevels.Any(p => p.Id == id));
```

Comment: Why do you need `ref`? You can pass around `List<T>` and mutate it...

Comment: Are each of the methods only reading data from the list, or are any of them making modifications to the list or the data within it?  How large is the list?

Comment: The normal way would be to pass them as argument (not by `ref`).

Comment: @Servy The list is fairly small but can grow. Probably no more than 100 complex objects. There is one method that is inserting into the list. The rest are just reading.

Comment: Can you show us the code in question, so we can see the context of the class. My answer would differ based on i.e. if this was a static utility class vs. an instance oriented class that models some object in the world.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I'm not sure, but I thought ref was like pointers for c#.

Comment: @proseidon `List` is a class, and as such it is a reference type.  When you have a variable that is of type `List` it doesn't actually contain the entire list, it contains a reference to that list.  Passing that using `ref` parameters is the C++ equivalent of a pointer to a pointer.  You don't need that in this context.

Comment: To eliminate the confusion of when to use `ref` have a read of @JonSkeet's article about C# parameters: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @Servy Okay. I am confused then. When I defined a private list in the main class, then defined it in a method, any other class that used the list still showed it as null. Why does this happen?

Comment: @proseidon Well, it's harder to say without code, but it seems like you defined a list variable and never actually assigned a list instance to it.

Comment: @proseidon Given your provided code snippets, if the list is null when you call the second method then it means you never called the `Bind` method first (at least not on the same object instance).  If you did, it was either set to null afterwards, or there was an error creating the list.

Comment: @Servy (sorry for the long comment thread, trying to learn), so what I did was `private list<object> stuff` in the class, and in the method I did `stuff = new list<object>(things from the database)`. Would the correct method be to start as `private list<object> stuff = new list<object>`?

Comment: @proseidon we were writing our comments at the same time.  To answer your last question no, you probably don't want to do that.  What you have in the OP is just fine, the problem is likely in some more code that's now shown.

Comment: * edit my last comment should say *not* shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, in general, how I'd do it. If you always use the same sequence of functions on a list, consider creating a chained function to handle that. You can also directly pass a function call inside one of the other function calls (as long as it returns a list), but that tends to look messy.

```
public List<int> DoSomethingWithList(List<int> list)
{
    //do stuff
    return list;
}

public List<int> DoSomethingElseWithList(List<int> list)
{
    //do other stuff
    return list;
}

public void SomeOtherFunction(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; //create list
    list = DoSomethingWithList(list); //change list
    list = DoSomethingElseWithList(list); //change list further
}
```

If you are working with an object that has a `List<T>` field, I'd do like this:

```
public class MyBigClass
{
    private List<int> myList;
    public MyBigClass()
    {
        //instantiate list in constructor
        myList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; 
    }

    public void PublicListAdder(int val)
    {
        myList.Add(val);
    }

    private void PrivateListCleaner()
    {
        //remove all even numbers, just an example
        myList.RemoveAll(x => x % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```

You rarely need to use `ref` in C#, because it automatically handles pointers for you. You are (usually) not passing around a struct, you are passing around an object reference (which basically is a pointer).

Comment: The only issue I came across with this is that I want to access the list in a Button event, and since the button event click is called from the web page, my code behind doesn't pass any parameters to the event.

Answer (score 0):

Your #1 and #2 don't really make sense:

1. If you define a different list in every method that uses it, then you're using a different list each time.  This is not sharing the list; this *doesn't* work.  If you mean "call your method that creates the list from each method that uses it" then the same still applies: you're using a different list each time.
2. You don't need to use `ref ListObjects` to update a private member; a private member is just accessed by its name.  This isn't bad practice; this is standard object-oriented practice.
3. Passing all required data *into* a method as parameters makes the method inherently more reusable as it reduces coupling to the class the method belongs to.

In short: #3 is good practice to an extent, as it increases the reusability of code.  However, the use of #2 is fundamentally the reason we have Object-Oriented programming: to *save* you from repeatedly passing parameters into all your methods.  This is exactly what private fields are designed for!

Comment: I would disagree with your comments as to #1.  You assume that he needs to share the list.  That isn't a stated requirement.  If each method only reads data then it doesn't matter if it's shared or not.  It's also possible that it's a requirement that the list **not** be shared.  There is not sufficient information to know which is the desired behavior.

Comment: He states "I want to define the list of objects in one method, and use them in several others."  I assume (maybe incorrectly) that this means sharing the list.  Perhaps the OP could elaborate.

Comment: The issue was is that I didn't want to access the database for a list multiple times if I can just access it once and use the list over and over again. There was no problem with the list being read multiple times because the database didn't change, but it wasn't efficient

Comment: @proseidon That is correct.  Given that your list is generated from accessing a database you will want to avoid generating it whenever possible, and to instead re-use it.  Until you added later edits that wasn't apparent.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, I would probably go with Anders' answer. Depending on your situation, another way that is worth considering is to write [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for List.

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static object DoSomething(this List<T> list)
        {
            //do the something with list
        }
    }   
}
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.DoSomething();
```

In that example, `list` is passed as the parameter to the extension method.

Comment: The issue seems to be how to pass a `List` around so that it can be accessed from multiple scopes.  (And whether this *should* be done or not.)  This doesn't seem relevant to that at all.

Comment: @Servy It is relevant because it is another way to work with a list across multiple method calls. He might not need to pass the list around to different methods if he can write extensions instead. It's not the simplest way, but it certainly has its usefulness.

Comment: It may be appropriate to have methods that take a `List` as a parameter (for which an extension method qualifies).  That is certainly one possible aspect of an answer to this question, but it's certainly not an answer in and of itself, and being an extension method has nothing to do with anything; the only reason this is mildly relevant is just that it's any old method that takes a `List` as one of it's parameters.

Comment: @Servy I'm not convinced you know what extension methods are. Either that or you're a troll.

Comment: An extension method is syntactic sugar that allows a static method to be called using syntax that makes it appear to be an instance method of the type that is the first parameter of that static method.  Using your method, it will internally transform (or do the equivalent of transforming) `list.DoSomething()` into `MyExtensions.DoSomething(list)`.

Comment: @Servy I stand corrected. I fail to see why you consider my answer "clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect" (per the SO etiquette) but apparently don't have a problem with Anders' answer.

Comment: Your answer would imply that using an extension method would allow you to do something above and beyond just creating a method that takes a `List` as a parameter.  It does not.  In fact, in context, it doesn't even appear to be an appropriate use of an extension method.  There is a class, it has several methods that need to modify one particular list.  What about that indicates an extension method should be created?  An extension method should be created if you find yourself frequently wishing to perform some particular action on instances of a particular type.

Comment: @Servy I think you're making some assumptions about the question that OP never included. Still, I see the point you're trying to make now.

Comment: Yes, I am making assumptions about details the OP hasn't included.  So far his edits/comments have been in line with my assumptions, but there is still more that we need to know.  In my mind the OP hasn't provided enough information for this question to be answered, which is why I haven't answered at all or upvoted any existing answer.

Answer (score -1):

Usually a `List<T>` shouldn't belong to the state of an instance and exposed since it's mutable and you may change the state from the outside otherwise -unless your getter is designed to return a readonly list. Unless your design clearly allow such a possibility when it may occur. My reply doesn't really answer to your question is just a suggestion of good object oriented design. As someone already suggested much better than me you may pass a List back and forth each method and directly modify it.

Comment: Lists can be instance variables of classes.  This is quite common.  Yes, you can do it unsafely if you expose the list too much, but that doesn't mean they shouldn't be used (or that they aren't used *all the time*).

Comment: of course!! but I explained why in this context! incredible. anyway it's ok...your explanation is so brilliant I have to upvote (sarcasm)

Comment: *"Usually a List<T> shouldn't belong to the state of an instance"*  I don't see how this is speaking to this specific user's example, since you have included nothing specific to this question in your answer.  The quoted statement is quite broad and appears to apply to...everything.

Comment: ok I'll correct the statement according my opinion and your highlight. thanks